# Turn a datatable into a two-dimensional list in R

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a data.table (see `dt`). I want to turn it into a 2-dimensional list for future use (e.g. `a`, `b` and `c` are column names of another `dt`. I want to select the value of a non-missing column among `a`, `b` and `c` then impute into `x`, and so on). So the 2-dimensional list will act like a reference object for `fcoalesce` function.

```
# example
dt <- data.table(col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
                 col2 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "z"))

# desirable result
list.1 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("d", "e"), c("f"))
list.2 <- list("x", "y", "z")

list(list.1, list.2)
```

Since the actual dt is much larger than the example dt, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand why you need this but the most efficient way is to just not do it. I bet you can avoid this step and continue working with the data.table.

Comment: The `dt` in the example is a reference table. The elements are variable names of another data.table I'm actually working with. What I really want is , for var `a`, `b` and `c`, theoretically, there will be only one of them have a non missing value. for each row. I want to assign that value to variable `x`. For variable `d` and `e`, I want to assign the non missing value to y, and so on .

Comment: @IanWang sounds like a job for a merge.

Comment: For now, I only came up with some structure like `DT[, x := fcoalesce(a, b, c) ]` In order to do this in batch, I thought a 2d list might come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()`:

```r
lst1 <- split(dt$col1, dt$col2)
lst2 <- as.list(names(lst1))
result <- list(unname(lst1), lst2)

result
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "d" "e"
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# [1] "f"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "x"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "y"
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# [1] "z"
```