# batch store non-missing value in a new column in data.table by a reference data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na, coalesce, imputation

I have a `dt.2` with columns including `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `d` and `e`. Some columns actually have the same meaning and could be used for imputation. For example, `a`, `b` and `c` equal to `x` while `d` and `e` equal to `y`. These replationships are recorded in another table `dt`.
I want to impute NA value to `x` and `y` by associated columns respectively.

In order to do this in batch, I created a 2 dimention list(object `result`) based on Darren Tsai's answer here [Turn a datatable into a two-dimensional list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105670/turn-a-datatable-into-a-two-dimensional-list-in-r?noredirect=1#comment132539526_75105670)

Then, I intended to use a `for` loop but kept getting error. Not sure if my direction was correct. Or if I overcomplicated this problem. Thanks!

```
library(data.table)
# data.table of reference
dt <- data.table(col1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 col2 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y"))

# data.table to work with
dt.2 <- data.table(a = c(1,  NA, 4),
                   b = c(NA, NA, 2),
                   c = c(NA, NA, NA),
                   x = c(NA, 3,  NA),
                   d = c(5,  6,  NA),
                   e = c(NA, NA, 7))

# my current code
lst1 <- split(dt$col1, dt$col2)
lst2 <- as.list(names(lst1))
result <- list(unname(lst1), lst2)

for(i in 1:2){
  new.col <- result[[2]][i][[1]]
  old.cols <- unique(result[[1]][i][[1]])

  dt.2[, new.col := fcoalesce(old.cols)]
}
```

Comment: Your current code results in an error...

Comment: yes, as I just figured out, it seems `fcoalesce` only accept column names without quote (e.g. `fcoalesce(col1, col2)`, rather than `fcoalesce("col1", col2)`).

Comment: Did you solve the whole question or just the error suggested by sindri_baldur? If you are still looking for input, what is your expected output?

Comment: No, I haven't solve this problem. My current code is both error and not efficient. The below answer is exactly what I need! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you need is for `x` to be *updated* and for `y` to be *created* based on the existing values of the other column names.

First, `c` is `logical` when it needs to be `as.numeric`. A literal fix is merely

```r
dt.2[, c := as.numeric(c)]
```

Try this:

```r
spl <- split(dt$col1, dt$col2)
spl <- Map(c, names(spl), spl)
spl
# $x
# [1] "x" "a" "b" "c"
# $y
# [1] "y" "d" "e"

dt.2[, names(spl) := lapply(spl, function(cols) do.call(fcoalesce, .SD[, intersect(cols, names(.SD)), with = FALSE]))]
dt.2
#        a     b     c     x     d     e     y
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1    NA    NA     1     5    NA     5
# 2:    NA    NA    NA     3     6    NA     6
# 3:     4     2    NA     4    NA     7     7
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It worked as expected. I still have one question. Since in your code, there was no `.SDcols` to specify the content of `.SD`, how does `data.table` know what columns to use when generating `.SD`?

Comment: When there is no `.SDcols=` provided, then `.SD` referred to all columns. And I used `with=FALSE`  so the `j` argument is interpreted as a character vector of column names.